# Input value not resetting on re-render of React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component which displays a modal. Displays fine the first time. But when I close and reopen it "holds" the input value: The code for the render method is:

```
 render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Button
          type="primary"
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({
                topup: 0,
                modalVisible: true
            });
          }}
        >
          Replace
        </Button>
        <Modal
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onOk={this.onOk}
          onCancel={() => {
            this.setState({
                topup: 0,
                modalVisible: false
            });
          }}
        >
          <Form>
            <Row gutter={24}>
              <Col span={24}>
                <Descriptions>
                  <Descriptions.Item label="Topup">
                    <Input 
                      type="number"
                      defaultValue={this.state.topup}
                      onChange={value => {
                        console.log('value.target.value is ', value.target.value);
                        if (Number(value.target.value)) {
                          this.setState({
                            ...this.state,
                            topup: Number(value.target.value) 
                          });
                        } 
                      }}
                    />
                  </Descriptions.Item>
                </Descriptions>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Form>
        </Modal>
      </>
    );
  }
```

When it first displays, the value in the `topup` Input is 0, which is correct. If I change to 10, then close the modal, I reset the state so the topup is 0. When I click the button, somehow, the Input still has 10. I can see in the state the `topup` property is 0. What could possible be going on?

Answer (score 0):

1. It might be because that Input is [uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values), as in you only provide default value, so maybe try using value instead of defaultValue if you want value to always come from state.
2. This is irrelevant to your problem, but if you're using this.setState method of class component, you don't need to spread this.state, because whatever you pass into this.setState [will be merged](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged) with current state. Also using old state to create new state like that can lead to bugs, so if you ever need to use old state to generate new one (for example, you want to increment state variable), [you should pass a function](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) into this.setState:

```js
this.setState((prevState)=>{
    return {
        value: prevState.value + 1
    };
});
```

That way React will handle your setState properly and guarantee prevState is actual current state at the moment setState is running.